# ¿Cómo remover una fila de un arreglo numpy en python?

Tags: python, base-de-datos

Necesito remover valores extremos de una grande base de datos almacenada en un arreglo numpy. Para ello, recorro el arreglo con un bucle y verifico los valores si los valores son mayores o menores de lo requerido. Una vez que encuentro esos valores intento deletar con `numpy.delete()`, pero esto crea una copia del vector anterior, lo para mi problema resultaria muy ineficiente.

```
import numpy as np

# Making a random numpy array
data_base = np.random.random(10)
data_base.resize((5,2))

#Defining limites
average_db = data_base.mean()
std_db = data_base.std()
upper = average_db + std_db*.5
lower = average_db - std_db*.5

# Prints
print('data_base = ', data_base)
print('upper = ', upper)
print('lower = ', lower)


for i in range(len(data_base)):
    if data_base[i,1]>=upper or data_base[i,1]<=lower:
        data_base = np.delete(data_base, i)

#for element in data_base:
#    if element[1]>=upper or element[1]<=lower:
#        data_base = np.delete(data_base, i)


print(data_base)
```

Como si fuera poco también tengo el siguiente problema

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/.../outliers.py", line 27, in <module>
    if data_base[i,1]>=upper or data_base[i,1]<=lower:
IndexError: too many indices
```

Comment: En la línea del `if` estás comparando un array/arreglo con un valor, por ello obtienes un `IndexError`. Viendo el código no se entiende muy bien cual es el resultado final que quieres conseguir. Por favor, explica un poco mejor, poniendo, por ejemplo, el array final que quieres obtener. Si usas valores ^random* puedes usar `np.random.seed` para que podamos reproducir tu ejemplo.

Comment: ok voy a expicar mejor en breve. Gracias por el consejo. En el if se tiene data_base[i,1] que es un elemento también, asi que creo que debería funcionar al ser comparado com un valor.

Answer (score 3):

Existen muchas formas de hacer lo que preguntas, aquí tienes una posible solución siguiendo tu desarrollo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

# Making a random numpy array
np.random.seed(123)  # optional 
data_base = np.random.random(10)
data_base.resize((5,2))

#Defining limits
average_db = data_base.mean()
std_db = data_base.std()
upper = average_db + std_db*.5
lower = average_db - std_db*.5

# Prints
print('data_base = ', data_base)
print('upper = ', upper)
print('lower = ', lower)

is_outlier = np.bitwise_or(data_base>=upper, data_base<=lower)

data_base_clean = np.extract(is_outlier, data_base)

print('data_base_clean = ', data_base_clean)
```

La ventaja de trabajar con arrays es que puedes comparar valores sin necesidad de moverte por cada uno de ellos mediante bucles for.

Lo único que te recomendaría es no eliminar los valores si no asignarles NaN, de esta forma tu array no pierde la forma aleatoriamente.